# Is there an equivalent for Message Compiler (MC.exe) for C#?

Tags: c#, .net, t4

**A little background:**

Message Compiler is a useful tool that transforms a Message Text File into a C/C++ header file and hence provides strong typing for messages.

Message Text File:

```
; // ***** Sample.mc *****
; // This is the header section.

MessageIdTypedef=DWORD

SeverityNames=(Success=0x0:STATUS_SEVERITY_SUCCESS
Informational=0x1:STATUS_SEVERITY_INFORMATIONAL
Warning=0x2:STATUS_SEVERITY_WARNING
Error=0x3:STATUS_SEVERITY_ERROR
)

FacilityNames=(System=0x0:FACILITY_SYSTEM
Runtime=0x2:FACILITY_RUNTIME
Stubs=0x3:FACILITY_STUBS
Io=0x4:FACILITY_IO_ERROR_CODE
)

LanguageNames=(English=0x409:MSG00409)
LanguageNames=(Japanese=0x411:MSG00411)

; // The following are message definitions.

MessageId=0x1
Severity=Error
Facility=Runtime
SymbolicName=MSG_BAD_COMMAND
Language=English
You have chosen an incorrect command.
```

Message Compiler(mc.exe) transforms the above into a header file:

```
..
#define MSG_BAD_COMMAND <some-hex-number>
..
```

This header file makes it easy to offer strong typing for error codes/messages.

In my case, I need to use the messages defined in the Message Text File in both C++ and C# code. So I need a transformation similar to:

```
public class SomeClass
{
   public const uint MSG_BAD_COMMAND = <some-hex-number>;
```

I would like to find a tool that would work out of the box and facilitate the transformation like mc.exe does.

Please suggest.

Comment: Unclear here, but maybe [xsd.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Project > Properties > Resources.  Look around some more, this is supposed to be discoverable.  Press F1 if you see something you don't understand.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn This looks promising, will report back with the results.